# What were Camus' views on nihilism and existentialism?

Tags: existentialism, nihilism, camus

I have recently become fairly interested in Camus. I'm not really that familiar with philosophy, but I do know the difference between nihilism and existentialism. I've been wondering what Camus thought about the two in relation to each other.

Comment: See [Camus](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/camus/) and [Existentialism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/existentialism/); Camus was an existentialism and not a nihilist : "“Does the absurd dictate death” (*The Myth of Sisyphus*)? the main concern of the book is to sketch ways of living our lives so as to make them worth living despite their being meaningless."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between nihilism and and existentialism is that nihilism proclaims that there is no meaning, whereas existentialism (mostly) states that each individual must decide their own meaning.

[The Myth of Sisyphus](http://dbanach.com/sisyphus.htm) written by Camus speaks of rolling a rock up a hill over and over only to have it fall back down. This is an interesting metaphor and Camus' argument against nihilism. The last two lines of the story I have quoted below, but you shoulds really read the entirety in a sitting when you have time.

> The struggle itself toward the heights is enough to fill a man's heart. One must imagine Sisyphus happy.

Comment: I did read it, but at the time I had not really understood the difference or even the concepts of nihilism and existentialism.